# GWT: Editing Text Of Tree Item

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

When a user clicks a 'Add Node' button above a tree and the program adds a tree item below the selected node, I would like to insert the new tree item with the text highlight and ready for editing by the user... like labels in GMail. Any ideas?

--Kirt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you using the GWT default [TreeItem](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TreeItem.html)?  If so, when you add the node, you could add the `TreeItem` with a `Widget` which you write which contains a `TextBox` and a `Button` to save.

When the save button is clicked, it calls `setText()` on the tree item with the text box's text, thus removing the widgets from the tree item.

It may be an even better idea to subclass `TreeItem` to encapsulate this logic and provide more functionality.

edit: Here, just because I'm feeling generous...

```
public class EditableTreeItem extends TreeItem {
  public EditableTreeItem() {
    super();
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    Button saveButton = new Button("Save");
    saveButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(ClickEvent e) {
        if (!textBox.getText().isEmpty()) {
          EditableTreeItem.this.setText(textBox.getText());
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```